# JavaでHTMLを取得し、getBytesで文字コードを変換すると「一部」文字化けする

Tags: android, java

以下のコードを走らせると、取得したデータの文字列が以下の画像のように一部化けて変換されます。

```
try {
    // 接続用HttpURLConnectionオブジェクト作成
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    // URLの作成
    URL urlSt = "https://cs.kintetsu-ls.co.jp/TR/TRGG0020/TRGG0020.aspx?ID=1234567890";
    url = new URL(urlSt);
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    // リダイレクトを自動で許可しない設定
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    // URL接続からデータを読み取る場合はtrue
    con.setDoInput(true);
    // URL接続にデータを書き込む場合はtrue
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    // 接続
    con.connect();
    // 本文の取得
    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
    String readSt = readInputStream(in);
    //文字コードを指定して変換する
    readSt = new String(readSt.getBytes("Shift_JIS"));

    System.out.println(readSt);//ここでブレークを張って、デバックエリアでreadStの中を覗いて取得文字をキャプチャ

    //切断
    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            if (con != null) con.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


public String readInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String st = "";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "Shift_JIS"));
    while((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(st);
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

[image: Shift-JIS変換後の文字列]

このように一部文字が化ける場合、どのようにしたら良いのでしょうか。

ご教示いただければ幸いです。

PS:UTF-8を指定すると、以下のようになります。

[image: UTF-8の結果]

以下が変換前です。

[image: 変換前]

Comment: コンパイルが通らない部分を直して、`readInputStream()`メソッドを適当に実装して確認したら、UF-8にすれば文字化けしない結果が取得できました。本文のコードをコンパイルの通るものに修正してください。それから`readInputStream()`メソッドも追加して下さい。

Comment: androidのタグを使っていますが、本当にandroidの実行結果なのでしょうか? また一部が文字化けする原因として一番可能性が高いのは`readInputStream`の実装が間違っているということです。メソッドの定義内容をお示しください。ちなみにあなたのコードで`readSt = new String(readSt.getBytes("Shift_JIS"));`は「文字コードを指定して変換する」ことにはならない意味のないコードです。「変換」前の`readSt`の内容はどのようになっていますか?

Comment: `readInputStream`をすっかり忘れていました。追加いたしました。変換前も追加いたしました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 書き忘れましたがAndroidStudioを使用してコードを書いており、キャプチャもそこからです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// バイト列をShift_JISとして解釈してUTF-16に変換
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "Shift_JIS"));
...
// UTF-16をShift_JISのバイト列に変換
byte[] bytes = readSt.getBytes("Shift_JIS")
// Shift_JISのバイト列を(デフォルトのUTF-8として解釈して)UTF-16に変換する
readSt = new String(bytes);
```

という流れになっているので、元のHTMLのUTF-8バイト列をShift_JISとして解釈、そのShift_JISをUTF-8として解釈という処理になっていて、たまたま共通のコードがある一部だけ2重に化けて正しいかのように見えている状態です。

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));`で読み込んだ文字列を`getBytes()`や`new String()`せずにそのまま使えば問題ないはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたとおりでした。解決いたしました。わかりやすく解説いただきありがとうございました。